# Product theorem - Fourier sequence transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, fourier-transform

On my book there is the following result:

$$z[n]=x[n]y[n]$$

$$Z(f)=T \int_{-1/2T}^{1/2T}{X(v)Y(v-f)dv}$$

I don't understand if ($*$=convolution):

$$Z(f)=TX(f)*Y(f)$$

or:

$$Z(f)=X(f)*Y(f)$$

Can you show me the right result please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague - I'm guessing $x[n]$, $y[n]$ and $z[n]$ are sequences of numbers (real or complex) indexed by $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and that $X(f)$, $Y(f)$ and $Z(f)$ are the corresponding discrete-time Fourier transforms (DTFT), e.g.
$$
X(f) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} x[n] e^{-i 2\pi f T n}.
$$

Then, as you say,
$$
z[n] = x[n] y[n] \implies Z(f) = T \int_{-\frac{1}{2T}}^{\frac{1}{2T}} X(v)Y(f-v)\,dv.
$$
If you want to write the right-hand side using a binary operator, both choices are valid, it is just a matter of conventions and defining the symbols you are using. I would go for the first option, since the [circular convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution) of two periodic functions (such as $X(f)$ and $Y(f)$, which have period $1/T$) is usually defined just by the integral, without normalization with respect to the period.

A natural, follow-up question is as to why we have to introduce the factor $T$, while in the classic (continuous) Fourier transform we just take the convolution. Of course, we can prove the result by just applying the definitions
\begin{align}
Z(f) &= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} x[n]y[n] e^{-i 2\pi f T n} \\
&= T \int_{-\frac{1}{2T}}^{\frac{1}{2T}} X(v) \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} y[n] e^{-i 2\pi (f-v) T n} \, dv &\text{(by computing $x[n]$ with the inverse trasf.)}\\
&= T \int_{-\frac{1}{2T}}^{\frac{1}{2T}} X(v) Y(f-v) \, dv &\text{(recognizing $Y(f-v)$ in the summation)}
\end{align}
but this approach doesn't really bring any insight about our question. Then, let's try a different proof.

In the following we will assume that $x[n]$ and $y[n]$ are obtained from two continuous signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, respectively, by sampling with period $T$ and scaling:
\begin{align}
x[n] &= Tx(nT) & y[n]&=Ty(nT).\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
\end{align}
The scaling is a common choice (see, e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Definition)), because it simplifies some calculations. For instance, under this assumption, we can write
\begin{align}
X(f) &= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{X}(f-n\,/\,T) &
Y(f) &= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{Y}(f-n\,/\,T) \tag{2}\label{eq:2}
\end{align}
where $\hat{X}(f)$ and $\hat{Y}(f)$ are the classic, continuous-time Fourier transforms of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, respectively, that is
\begin{align}
\hat{X}(f) &= \mathcal{F}\bigl\{x(t)\bigr\} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) \, e^{-i 2\pi f t} \, dt &
\hat{Y}(f) &= \mathcal{F}\bigl\{y(t)\bigr\} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} y(t) \, e^{-i 2\pi f t} \, dt.\tag{3}\label{eq:3}
\end{align}

Now, recall that, since $e^{-i 2\pi f T n}$ is the Fourier transform of $\delta(t-nT)$, we can write
$$
Z(f) = \mathcal{F}\biggl\{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} z[n]\delta(t-nT)\biggr\}
= \mathcal{F}\biggl\{T^2 x(t) y(t) \Psi_T(t)\biggr\}
$$
where we introduced the Dirac comb $\Psi_T(t) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \delta(t-nT)$ and where we used the fact that $z[n]=x[n]y[n]=T^2 x(nT) y(nT)$, which stems from (\ref{eq:1}).

Next, we can use the properties of the (classic) Fourier transform and write
$$
Z(f) = T^2 \hat{X}(f) * \hat{Y}(f) * \frac{1}{T}\Psi_{\frac{1}{T}}(f) = T \hat{X}(f) * \hat{Y}(f) * \Psi_{\frac{1}{T}}(f)
$$
where $\hat{X}(f)$ and $\hat{Y}(f)$ are as defined in (\ref{eq:3}), while $\frac{1}{T}\Psi_{\frac{1}{T}}(f) = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \delta(f-n\,/\,T)$ is the (continuous-time) Fourier transform of $\Psi_T(t)$. Also, $*$ denotes the standard convolution
$$
a(f) * b(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} a(v) b(f-v)\,dv.
$$
Finally, since $\hat{Y}(f) * \Psi_{\frac{1}{T}}(f) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{Y}(f-n\,/\,T)$, we can use (\ref{eq:2}) to rewrite $Z(f)$ as
\begin{align}
Z(f) &= T \hat{X}(f) * Y(f) \\
&= T \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} Y(v) \hat{X}(f-v) \,dv \\
&= T \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{n\,/\,T}^{(n+1)\,/\,T} Y(v) \hat{X}(f-v) \,dv \\
&= T \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{0}^{1\,/\,T} Y(v-n\,/\,T) \hat{X}(f-v+n\,/\,T) \,dv &\text{(change of variable $v \mapsto v-n\,/\,T$)}\\
&= T \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{0}^{1\,/\,T} Y(v) \hat{X}(f-v+n\,/\,T) \,dv &\text{($Y(v)$ is $1\,/\,T$-periodic)}\\
&= T \int_{0}^{1\,/\,T} Y(v) \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{X}(f-v+n\,/\,T) \,dv \\
&= T \int_{0}^{1\,/\,T} Y(v) X(f-v) \,dv
\end{align}
where, again, we used (\ref{eq:2}) in the last step.

This proof, at least in my opinion, clarifies that there is nothing special about the DTFT and that the factor $T$ in the "convolution-theorem" identity appears as a consequence of sampling.

Comment: Hello @dvdgrgrtt why $z[n]=x[n]y[n]=T^2 x(nT) y(nT)$?

Comment: It's because I'm using the common convention $x[n]=Tx(nT)$ and $y[n]=Ty(nT)$, so that one can easily compare with the Wikipedia entry on [DTFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Definition). Then, if you plug these expressions into the definition of $z[n]$ you get $z[n]=x[n]y[n]=Tx(nT)\,Ty(nT)=T^2x(nT)y(nT)$. I rewrote part of the answer to make this clearer and highlight one of the advantages of this choice.